# Isomorphism of Real Quaternions and Complex Matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, quaternions

I have to prove that the ring of real quaternions, is isomorphic to

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z & w\\
-\bar{w} & \bar{z}\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
Where $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, and $\bar{z}$, $\bar{w}$ their conjugates.

My question is, if I define 
$1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$
, 
$i=
\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
0 & -i\\
\end{pmatrix}$
, $j=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$
and 
$k=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & i\\
i & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} 
 $

As my isomorphism, and I notice that $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$ and that also happens in the matrix. Is that enough to prove the isomorphism? Or do I have to show something else?

Comment: Yes, basically that's it.
But please rather use an assignment notation $\mapsto$ rather than equality, as an isomorphism is a *function* which has inverse.

Comment: Ooo yes you are right. My mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prove that the the quaternions and the matrices of this form are isomorphic as [skew fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring).  Tis means that the addition of two quaternions correspond to the addition of the corresponding matrices and the same for the product  and vice-versa, and that all required properties are satisfied ( this is easy). Also you have to prove that the inverse of a quaternion correspond to the inverse of a matrix,  this is a consequence of the fact that , if the quaternion $z$ correspond to the matrix $Z$, we have $\det Z=|z|^2$.
To complete  the proof, we have also to consider that the quaterions are a ring with an involution ( the conjugation) so we have to prove also tha we can define an involution in the ring of matrices and that the conjugate of a quaternion is the conjugate of the corresponding matrix.

Comment: I don't know why you say you need to prove the inverse property separately.  It suffices, and I think is more straightforward, to prove there is a bijective ring homomorphism.